# How to create Star Schema Benchmark(SSB) tables?

Tags: star-schema

I am trying to generate SSB tables by getting github.
https://github.com/electrum/ssb-dbgen
but, it can't run the `dbgen' program from it.
Please how to create the tables Correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. From that source code, you can't generate tables.
but another user fixed the source and you can find that on github.
Here you can download and hope it works!
https://github.com/LucidDB/thirdparty/blob/master/ssb.tar.bz2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.